# How can i use OpenLayers in Android

Tags: android, openlayers

I want to use OpenLayers in Android project but i didn't find any API for mobile.

I looked [here](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/mobile-navigation.html) but it is JavaScript.. I don't know anything about using javascript in Android.

How can i use OpenLayers in Android ?

Is there any API for Android ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "special" API for android.  Openlayers JavaScript library is made for use in web pages.  If you create a web page that uses Openlayers, it can be viewed and used by Android devices.  Openlayers even supports multitouch events.